# Need to pass a PHP variable in Kohana 3.1 from a base controller to another controller which is loaded via AJAX with jQuery UI tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, kohana-3

I've tried setting global variables with set/bind_global() and what not, but nothing's working.

So here's my layout, and please let me know if you have any suggestions or tips on anything you see:

Controller_Common extends Controller_Template, and sets up the Facebook PHP API and creates a FB session, as well as creating arrays for the JS and CSS files which are then included in the template view.

Inside the template view, I am using jQuery tabs with three different tabs. Each tab loads via AJAX another controller inside its corresponding div element.

Mostly what I want to do is, pass the Facebook session info (namely the uid, name, etc) from the Controller_Common controller to the controller inside the jQuery tab, which is of course loaded dynamically.

Is this even possible without having to resort to a php session?

Also, is there a better solution to loading the controllers in the jQuery tabs than just setting the href equal to the relative url of the controller I want to call?  I'm shooting for best practice on all of the above, if possible.

Many thanks in advance,

Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I know I said I wanted to do this without using PHP sessions, but since I'm only wanting to carry over some basic info, I undecided not to use it.  For this situation, PHP sessions is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can generate Ajax calls with FB data you need. 
   Just pass var into template view and
   then set up JS vars like this (syntax may differ of course):

   ```
   var userId = <?php echo $fb->userId ?>;
   ```

   And later, your ajax loader will use userId var (as GET or POST param).
2. Why dont use FB API object in Ajax
   controller? So you dont need to pass
   a lot of data, which is already
   stored on a server side and is
   accessible.

Comment: 1.I had tried this but the JS variable was undefined within my jQuery tab content.

2. I wanted to try and save on the overhead of making an API call every time I needed to get the user's FB id.

The only other solution I could think of was to set an attribute on some div with the user's FB uid, but it didn't seem very graceful. I suppose it beats having to resort to globals though.